# Hide QScrollBar arrows

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qtstylesheets

How to hide `QScrollBar` arrows?

I need to hide in horizontal scrollbar.
I was trying to hide with `setStyleSheet`:

```
setStyleSheet(" QScrollBar:left-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal { height:0px; }" )
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to hide just the arrows inside buttons then you can try to set background and border in this way:

```
QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::left-arrow:horizontal
{
      border: none;
      background: none;
      color: none;
}
```

If you want to hide whole buttons then you go with code below.

```
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
      border: none;
      background: none;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
      border: none;
      background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but I've ran into an issue with this question's approved answer, and I've found a fix for it so I'm going to leave this here in case someone runs into the same problem that I did.

While [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25989355/7321499) suggests setting `border`, `background` and `color` to `none`, this only *visually* hides the scrollbar arrows. What I mean by this is that you can still click them, and the scrollbar's handle, while it can move to the place they occupied, can *not* be clicked on if your cursor is in the area the arrow buttons occupied.

To also functionally hide them, you should set their `width` and `height` styles to `0px` as well. This will make it so you *can* click on the handle if the scrollbar's handle is in the area the arrow-buttons occupied.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `QScrollBar` and assign it this stylesheet and this should do the trick. See example below.

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
  width: 15px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
  background: #888;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

QScrollBar::handle:hover:vertical {
  background: #555;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, instead of commenting please edit your answers to include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide a scroll bar you can set the scroll bar policy for that particular scroll bar (horizontal in your case). For example:

```
QScrollBar scrollBar;
scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Comment: I need to hide **arrows** of scroll bar not whole it.