# C++ Resize QScrollBar up-arrow

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

```
auto bar = ui->verticalScrollBar();
bar->setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:vertical { width: 20px; }" 
                   "QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollbar::down-arrow:vertical { width: 15px; height: 15px; }");
```

- I cannot resize the arrows.  [scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Khe.jpg)
- Already checked stylesheet example here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/stylesheet-examples.html

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the size of a QScrollBar's arrows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258487/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-qscrollbars-arrows)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `min-width`, `max-width` (the same value), `min-height`, `max-height` (the same value) instead of `width` and `height`.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't change anything.