# How to set a stylesheet for the QScrollBar in a QScrollArea?

Tags: pyqt, qtstylesheets

I can't figure out how to set a stylesheet to modify the `QScrollBar` in a `QScrollArea`.

I've first tried:

```
scrollarea = QScrollArea()
scrollarea.verticalScrollBar().setStyleSheet("""
    QScrollBar:horizontal {
        min-width: 240px;
        height: 13px;
    }

    QScrollBar:vertical {
        min-height: 240px;
        width: 13px;
    }

    QScrollBar::groove {
        background: gray;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle {
        background: blue;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
        width: 25px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
        height: 25px;
    }"""
# same for horizontalScrollBar
```

Then I tried applying the exact same stylesheet directly on the `QScrollArea` instance, with no success.

Then I tried to define the scrollbar myself :

```
scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
verticalScrollBar = QScrollBar(qt.Qt.Vertical, scrollArea)
verticalScrollBar.setStyleSheet(my_stylesheet)
scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBar(verticalScrollBar)
```

But the exact same stylesheet works on a `QSlider` (by replacing `QScrollBar` with `QSlider`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QScrollBar, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.scrollbar1 = QScrollBar(Qt.Vertical, self)
        self.scrollbar2 = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)

        for widget in [self.scrollbar1, self.scrollbar2]:
            widget.valueChanged.connect(self.test)
            self.layout.addWidget(widget)

    def test(self, event):
        print(self.sender().value())


stylesheet = """
    /* --------------------------------------- QScrollBar  -----------------------------------*/
    QScrollBar:horizontal
    {
        height: 15px;
        margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
        border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: yellow;    /* #2A2929; */
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:horizontal
    {
        background-color: blue;      /* #605F5F; */
        min-width: 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal
    {
        margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow_disabled.png);
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: right;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal
    {
        margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/left_arrow_disabled.png);
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: left;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow.png);
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: right;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }


    QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/left_arrow.png);
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: left;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
    {
        background: none;
    }


    QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
    {
        background: none;
    }

    QScrollBar:vertical
    {
        background-color: #2A2929;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
        border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:vertical
    {
        background-color: red;         /* #605F5F; */
        min-height: 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
    {
        margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow_disabled.png);
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: top;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
    {
        margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow_disabled.png);
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: bottom;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow.png);
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: top;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: bottom;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
    {
        background: none;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
    {
        background: none;
    }
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)       # <----
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.resize(300, 200)
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Upload images from a resource file.
This way is to convert
the res.qrc file in the res_rc.py file through the pyrcc5 file,
which can be directly loaded by import.

In a directory, for example `images` were put images: `right_arrow.png, ...`

Created a file such as `stylesheet.qrc`:

```xml
 <RCC>
 <qresource prefix="/">
     <file>images/down_arrow.png</file>
     <file>images/down_arrow_disabled.png</file>
     <file>images/up_arrow.png</file>
     <file>images/up_arrow_disabled.png</file>
     <file>images/left_arrow.png</file>
     <file>images/left_arrow_disabled.png</file>
     <file>images/right_arrow.png</file>
     <file>images/right_arrow_disabled.png</file>
 </qresource>
 </RCC>
```

Convert stylesheet.qrc to stylesheet_rc.py
`pyrcc5 stylesheet.qrc -o stylesheet_rc.py`

Paste into `main.py` - `import stylesheet_rc`

Transfer the modules `main.py` and `stylesheet_rc.py` to some other directory and run `main.py`

**main.py**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QScrollBar, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

import stylesheet_rc                                       # <--------                           

class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.scrollbar1 = QScrollBar(Qt.Vertical, self)
        self.scrollbar2 = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)

        for widget in [self.scrollbar1, self.scrollbar2]:
            widget.valueChanged.connect(self.test)
            self.layout.addWidget(widget)

    def test(self, event):
        print(self.sender().value())


stylesheet = """
    /* --------------------------------------- QScrollBar  -----------------------------------*/
    QScrollBar:horizontal
    {
        height: 15px;
        margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
        border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: yellow;    /* #2A2929; */
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:horizontal
    {
        background-color: blue;      /* #605F5F; */
        min-width: 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal
    {
        margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
        border-image: url(:/images/right_arrow_disabled.png);       /* # <-------- */
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: right;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal
    {
        margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
        border-image: url(:/images/left_arrow_disabled.png);        /* # <-------- */ 
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: left;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/images/right_arrow.png);               /* # <-------- */
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: right;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }


    QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/images/left_arrow.png);               /* # <-------- */
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: left;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
    {
        background: none;
    }


    QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
    {
        background: none;
    }

    QScrollBar:vertical
    {
        background-color: #2A2929;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
        border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:vertical
    {
        background-color: red;         /* #605F5F; */
        min-height: 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
    {
        margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
        border-image: url(:/images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        /* # <-------- */
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: top;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
    {
        margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
        border-image: url(:/images/down_arrow_disabled.png);       /* # <-------- */
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: bottom;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/images/up_arrow.png);                  /* # <-------- */
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: top;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on
    {
        border-image: url(:/images/down_arrow.png);                /* # <-------- */
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        subcontrol-position: bottom;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
    }

    QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
    {
        background: none;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
    {
        background: none;
    }
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)       # <----
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.resize(300, 200)
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: It works for QScrollBar when used directly, but not for a QScrollArea.

Comment: It actually works, thanks! I must have introduced an error invalidating the stylesheet, the first time I tried it.
Could you please explain the trick used to remove the arrow icons? It seems to be the lines that end with ``...arrow_disabled.png``. Is this an empty image? Can I rely on it to be shipped with all versions of Qt?

Comment: I added an update.
@PiRK If my answer helps you do not forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks again. I marked your answer as the right one. I did find a much simpler way to hide the arrow icons : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25989355/4494781

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that the stylesheet for `QSlider` and `QScrollBar` have sligthly different syntaxes.

My eventual solution is (to be set either as the `QScrollArea` stylesheet or as the `QApplication` stylesheet, depending on the desired scope):

```
stylesheet = """
    QScrollArea {
        border: none;
    }

    QScrollBar {
        background: gray;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    QScrollBar:horizontal {
        height: 13px;
    }

    QScrollBar:vertical {
        width: 13px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle {
        background: green;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
        height: 25px;
        min-width: 10px;
    }

    QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
        width: 25px;
        min-height: 10px;
    }

    QScrollBar::add-line {
        border: none;
        background: none;
    }

    QScrollBar::sub-line {
        border: none;
        background: none;
    }
    """
```