# Hide QScrollBar arrows using stylesheets

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qscrollbar

I am trying to get rid of the arrows of a vertical QScrollBar as part of a QListWidget by applying a stylesheet using Qt 5.15.

As I don't want weird behavior at the top and bottom, simply hiding the arrows as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157195/hide-qscrollbar-arrows/25989355#25989355) is insufficient. One answer to this question suggests to set the `width` and `height` of the arrows to `0px`, which I tried using

```
setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:vertical::up-arrow, QScrollBar:vertical::down-arrow {height: 0px;}");
```

but this results in the scrollbar not showing up. Forcing it to show up by using

```
setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
```

on the QListWidget results in the standard scrollbar to show up.

Interestingly enough, using any non-zero height, e.g. `30px` leads to the same results while changing the width works perfectly fine (although the width is then applied to the whole scrollbar but that is beside the point).

How can I achieve this without rewriting all mouseEvents?

Answer (score 0):

[musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) said:

> Note that when setting one property or subcontrol for a complex widget like QScrollBar, you must set all the other properties too ([see the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls)). At least you need to also set the properties for the `: handle` and the `:groove`. Check the [examples for QScrollBar customization](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar).

Based on that I found out that I had the wrong idea about add-line and sub-line as well as the arrows.

The following code managed to hide the arrows:

```
setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:vertical { background: transparent; width: 10px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }"
              "QScrollBar::add-line:vertical { border: 0px; height: 0px; }"
              "QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical { border: 0px; height: 0px; }");
```

Setting the width of `QScrollBar:vertical` is optional but changing the background color appears to be required.